# Clojure's equivalent to Lisp's atom function

Tags: clojure, lisp

I have this Lisp code, and I'm trying to convert it into Clojure code.

```
(defun copy-tree (tr)
  (if (atom tr)
    tr
    (cons (copy-tree (car tr))
          (copy-tree (crd tr)))))
```

It seems like that Clojure doesn't have Lisp's atom (or atom in Clojure has very different meaning), I had to modify the code as follows. ([Am I using atom? wrong or there is something else....?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782534/am-i-using-atom-wrong-or-there-is-something-else))

```
(defn single-valued?
     [x]
     (not (or (nil? x) 
              (.. x getClass isArray)
              (some #(instance? % x) [clojure.lang.Counted
                                      clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection
                                      java.util.Collection
                                      java.util.Map]))))

(defn copy-tree [tr]
  (if (or (= tr ()) (single-valued? tr))
    tr
    (cons (copy-tree (first tr))
          (copy-tree (rest tr)))))
```

The code works fine, but is there better way to replace Lisp's `atom` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find this behaves apropriately:

```
(def single-valued? (complement coll?))
```

the difference is that it will bottom out sooner for `nil` -- `(rest nil)` is `()` which finally does not recur, but `((complement coll?) nil)` returns `true`, so stops the recursion one step sooner.

Comment: I thought there was a pitfall here with lazy sequences. But they too implement `IPersistentCollection`: `(coll? (range))` => `true`. Good!